Bot that will ping users who used reaction X in the thread
Right now my bot responds to a message in different channel and creates thread of its own message.
How do I get users that reacted to a message it responded to so I can mention them in the thread it creates later on?
    if user == reaction.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "":
        channel = client.get_channel(1285915841254395956)

        # Filter out mention at the start
        mention_regex = re.compile(r"^<@&(\d+)> ")
        filtered_content = mention_regex.sub("", reaction.message.content, 1)
        print(filtered_content)

        message = await channel.send(f"{filtered_content} by {reaction.message.author.mention}")
        await message.add_reaction("")
        await message.channel.create_thread(name=message.content, message=None, auto_archive_duration=1440, reason=None)

Full code: https://codeshare.io/ONeQmA
Struggling with that.
